# how to implement transport for sqlresult set?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

```
    January February March April
  500     200      300   400
```

below is my code for this:

```
select 
 sum (case when [Month] = 1 then forecastdemand else 0.0  end ) January,
 sum(case when [Month] = 2 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) February,
  sum(case when [Month] = 3 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) March ,
 sum(case when [Month] = 4 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) April ,
 sum(case when [Month] = 5 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) May ,
 sum(case when [Month] = 6 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) June ,
  sum(case when [Month] = 7 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) July ,
 sum(case when [Month] = 8 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) August ,
  sum(case when [Month] = 9 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) September ,
 sum(case when [Month] = 10 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) October ,
 sum(case when [Month] = 11 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) November ,
 sum(case when [Month] = 12 then forecastdemand  else 0.0 end) December 
from forecastreorder as result
where Productid = 2
```

how can i make it into

```
  Month     Result
January   500
February  200
March     300
April     400
```

i know that i can use pivot unpivot for it but how can i apply it??
thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when [Month] = 1 then 'January'
             when [Month] = 2 then 'February'
             when [Month] = 3 then 'March'
             when [Month] = 4 then 'April'
        end) as Mon, sum(forecastdemand) as Result           
from forecastreorder fr
where Productid = 2 and
      [Month] in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by [Month]
order by [Month];
```